# How to set different type for variable in POJO than expected while deserializing json using gson in android(see example)

Tags: gson, json-deserialization, android-json

Bear with my English. I have a simple json,

```
{
    "Hint2": "L"
}
```

this is the POJO that works.

```
 public class Hints {
    @SerializedName("Hint2")
    @Expose
    private String Hint2;

   public void setHint1(Object Hint2) {
      this.Hint2 = (Hint2);
   }
 }
```

i want to change it to

```
public class Hints {
    @SerializedName("Hint2")
    @Expose
    public final ObservableField<String> Hint2 = new ObservableField<>();

   public void setHint2(String Hint2) {
      this.Hint2.set(Hint2);
   }
}
```

both class has same setter method, same @SerializedName annotation tag. only type of Hint2 object is changed. but the latter one throws exception shown below

```
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at..
```

so i believe deserialization depends on what kind of variable "Hint2" is. 

 Is there a way to make it work with ObservableField rather than using String?

The reason i'm trying this is android binding library, which supports binding objects directly to xml files. and the ObservableField automatically updates UI when corresponding value in POJO is changed.

**Update:**

[gson design document](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-design-document) has this

Using fields vs getters to indicate Json elements

*Some Json libraries use the getters of a type to deduce the Json elements. We chose to use all fields (up the inheritance hierarchy) that are not transient, static, or synthetic. We did this because not all classes are written with suitably named getters. Moreover, getXXX or isXXX might be semantic rather than indicating properties. 

However, there are good arguments to support properties as well. We intend to enhance Gson in a latter version to support properties as an alternate mapping for indicating Json fields. **For now, Gson is fields-based.***

so this indicates that Gson is fields-based. this pretty much answers my question but still waiting if anyone has someway around this.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same requirements, and resolved it finally, here are the steps:

1. create the class GsonUtils:

```
    public class GsonUtils {
        // code following
        //...
    }
```

following code are in this class

2. write a customized serializer & deserializer:

```
    private static class ObservableFieldSerializerDeserializer implements JsonSerializer>, JsonDeserializer> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(ObservableField src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return context.serialize(src.get());
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableField deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
            final Type type = ((ParameterizedType) typeOfT).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
            return new ObservableField((T) GsonUtils.getGson().fromJson(json, type));
        }
    }
```

3. you need to register ObservableField types to Gson:

```
    private static GsonBuilder createGsonBuilder() {
        final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<ObservableField<String>>(){}.getType(), new ObservableFieldSerializerDeserializer<String>());
        ...// register more types which are wrapped by ObservableFields
        return gsonBuilder;
    }
```

4. create the Gson which is used by the deserializer

```
    private static final Gson sGson = createGson();

    private static Gson createGson() {
        return createGsonBuilder().create();
    }

    // this is used by the deserializer
    public static Gson getGson() {
        return sGson;
    }
```

that's all, hope it helps

Comment: you can replace `GsonUtils.getGson().fromJson(` with `context.deserialize(`

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into what I think is the same issue, and here is a JUnit4 test showing how I solved it with Jackson for a POJO, but of course String would work as well.

```
public class ObservableDeserializationTest {

private static class ObservableDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<ObservableField> implements ContextualDeserializer {

    private Class<?> mTargetClass;

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException {
        mTargetClass = property.getType().containedType(0).getRawClass();
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableField deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObservableField result = new ObservableField();
        result.set(p.readValueAs(mTargetClass));
        return result;
    }
}

private static class SomePojo {
    public String id;
    public String name;
}

private static class ObservableTestClass {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = ObservableDeserializer.class)
    public ObservableField<SomePojo> testObj = new ObservableField<>();

}

@Test
public void DeserializingAnObservableObjectShouldSetValueCorrectly() {
    ObservableTestClass tc = null;
    try {
        tc = new ObjectMapper().readValue("{\"testObj\":{\"name\":\"TestName\",\"id\":\"TestId\"}}", ObservableTestClass.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Assert.assertEquals("TestName", tc.testObj.get().name);
    Assert.assertEquals("TestId", tc.testObj.get().id);
}

}
```

The key is the ContextualDeserializer interface that allows extracting the contained class type. Jackson provides several options for registering a custom deserializer, so this is but one way of doing it. Also, it would probably be a good idea to override getNullValue as well in the deserializer if you would use this for real.